# How much space do I need on my dvd-r for the LiveCD of 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, live-cd

I'm going to install Ubuntu version 12.04 but I don't know how much space on an empty dvd-r or cd-r I would need. Does anybody know? Also can you install Ubuntu directly on your hard drive? please help!

Answer (score 6):

The standard desktop CD install image is just under 700 MB, the DVD image is at most 1.6 GB. A standard 700 MB or higher blank CD or any blank DVD will do (you can also use a USB thumb drive).

You'll need to boot from your chosen install media (CD, DVD or USB drive) to install.

If you haven't already read the [official instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop) I would highly recommend you do so.

Comment: the CD is sufficient for most people as the download page says, the DVD is mostly for installs that want to include all the language packs.  FYI ii is possible to install directly to the hard disk, there are several question on askubuntu that describe how, but it is not recommended, unstable internet connections can cause errors in the installation.  The LiveCD will also allow you to try Ubuntu and make sure that it will work with your hardware. Great answer BTW, I was typing mine when yours was posted, mine became redundant So I deleted..

Comment: A good question, also, in that it's not that easy to find the answer, especially for someone who is new and might not be able to follow the trail to fine out.  It really should be more easily available right at the download link.  Hopefully, I didn't miss something obvious! :)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing @MartyFried they sure hide the information well.  Even the system retirements are hard to find, you have to go to the bottom right of the download page/  Unless I missed something as well.  Both of these bits of information should have an link on the main page....